# ¿Como actualizar correctamente una activity después de cerrar un fragmento?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-adapter

Quiero actualizar la vista de mi activity cada vez que vuelva de algún fragmento, pues el usuario realiza cambios de la lista desde alguno de ellos pero aveces la lista no se actualiza, ni siquiera con el metodo   getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener... y quedan datos desactualizados.

**Ejemplo:** si el usuario cambia de ciudad, la publicidad tiene que cambiar, y de hecho lo hace en la programación, pero no en la vista.

> Ya sé qué con firebase puedo detectar cambios como estos y actualizarlos pero no quiero utilizarlo para aquí.

Tambien quisiera que me comentaran si hay mejores practicas de llamar un adaptador desde una actividad.

```html
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);


        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        recyclerViewItems = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reciclerItems);
        recyclerViewPopular = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reciclerMasPopular);
        recyclerViewPublicidad = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_publicidad);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
        myAppPrefsManager = new MyAppPrefsManager(InicioActivity.this);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.customerID = sharedPreferences.getString("userID", "");
        customers_default_address_id = sharedPreferences.getString("userDefaultAddressID", "");
        app = ((App) getApplicationContext());
        newInstance(customerID);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(ConstantValues.APP_HEADER);
        publicidadInicioList  = new ArrayList<>();
        publicidadPopular = new ArrayList<>();

        final AppSettingsDetails appSettings = ((App) getApplicationContext()).getAppSettingsDetails();
        if(appSettings != null) {
            publicidadInicioList = ((App) getApplicationContext()).getPublicidadDetails();
            publicidadPopular = ((App) getApplicationContext()).getPublicidadPopular();
        }
        else{
            if(changeTask.isCancelled())
                changeTask.execute();
            else{
                changeTask.cancel(true);
                changeTask.execute();
            }
        }

        new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.END, false, new GravitySnapHelper.SnapListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSnap(int position) {
                Log.d("Snapped", position + "");
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewPopular);

        PublicidadPopularAdapter publicidadPopularAdapter = new PublicidadPopularAdapter(getApplicationContext(), publicidadPopular);
        recyclerViewPopular.setAdapter(publicidadPopularAdapter);
        recyclerViewPopular.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getParent(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        recyclerViewPopular.setHasFixedSize(true);
        publicidadPopularAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        PublicidadInicioAdapter publicidadInicioAdapter = new PublicidadInicioAdapter(getApplicationContext(), publicidadInicioList);
        recyclerViewPublicidad.setAdapter(publicidadInicioAdapter);
        recyclerViewPublicidad.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getParent(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerViewPublicidad.setHasFixedSize(true);
        publicidadInicioAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
                    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                }
                else{
                    actionBar.setTitle(ConstantValues.APP_HEADER);
                    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
                    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

                    if(appSettings != null) {
                        publicidadInicioList = ((App) getApplicationContext()).getPublicidadDetails();
                        publicidadPopular = ((App) getApplicationContext()).getPublicidadPopular();

                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                publicidadPopular = ((App) getApplicationContext()).getPublicidadPopular();
                                PublicidadPopularAdapter publicidadPopularAdapter = new PublicidadPopularAdapter(getApplicationContext(), publicidadPopular);
                                recyclerViewPopular.setAdapter(publicidadPopularAdapter);
                                recyclerViewPopular.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getParent(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
                                recyclerViewPopular.setHasFixedSize(true);
                                publicidadPopularAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                publicidadInicioList = ((App) getApplicationContext()).getPublicidadDetails();
                                PublicidadInicioAdapter publicidadInicioAdapter = new PublicidadInicioAdapter(getApplicationContext(), publicidadInicioList);
                                recyclerViewPublicidad.setAdapter(publicidadInicioAdapter);
                                recyclerViewPublicidad.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getParent(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                                recyclerViewPublicidad.setHasFixedSize(true);
                                publicidadInicioAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }, 300);
                    }else{

                        if(changeTask.isCancelled())
                        changeTask.execute();
                        else{
                            changeTask.cancel(true);
                            changeTask.execute();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Check BackStackEntryCount of FragmentManager
            }
        });

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
                    onBackPressed();
            }
        });


        itemsInicio();
        prueba();
        toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SheetDialogInfo bottomSheet = new SheetDialogInfo();
                bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "example");
            }
        });

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                publicidadPopular = ((App) getApplicationContext()).getPublicidadDetails();

                PublicidadPopularAdapter publicidadPopularAdapter = new PublicidadPopularAdapter(getApplicationContext(), publicidadPopular);
                recyclerViewPopular.setAdapter(publicidadPopularAdapter);
                recyclerViewPopular.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getParent(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
                recyclerViewPopular.setHasFixedSize(true);
                publicidadPopularAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                publicidadInicioList = ((App) getApplicationContext()).getPublicidadDetails();
                PublicidadInicioAdapter publicidadInicioAdapter = new PublicidadInicioAdapter(getApplicationContext(), publicidadInicioList);
                recyclerViewPublicidad.setAdapter(publicidadInicioAdapter);
                recyclerViewPublicidad.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getParent(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                recyclerViewPublicidad.setHasFixedSize(true);
                publicidadInicioAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


    }
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Una forma adecuada para establecer una comunicación *Fragment-Activity* podría ser a través de una **interfaz** (que la Activity implemente y el Fragment utilice para comunicarse con ella).

Por ejemplo, imagina esta simple interfaz:

```
interface UserListener {
  fun onUserChanged()
}
```

La Activity podría implementarla y sobreescribir el método `onUserChanged()`:

```
class YourActivity : Activity(), UserListener {
  // your code...

  override fun onUserChanged() {
    // update your data
  }
}
```

Y el Fragment a su vez, como tiene acceso a una instancia de **UserListener** a través de la Activity a la que pertenece, podría comunicarse haciendo uso de dicho método:

```
class YourFragment : Fragment() {

  // your code...

  // Inform when you want to communicate with your Activity
  val userListener = activity as UserListener
  userListener.onUserChanged()

}
```

Y esto sería todo. Suerte! ;)